# Evaluate:- $\frac{[4 + \sqrt{15}]^{3/2} + [4 - \sqrt{15}]^{3/2}}{[6 + \sqrt{35}]^{3/2} - [6 - \sqrt{35}]^{3/2}}$

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus, problem-solving

> Evaluate:- $\dfrac{[4 + \sqrt{15}]^{3/2} + [4 - \sqrt{15}]^{3/2}}{[6 + \sqrt{35}]^{3/2} - [6 - \sqrt{35}]^{3/2}}$

**What I Tried**:- Let $a = 4 , b = \sqrt{15} , c = 6, d= \sqrt{35}$ . Then I get :-
$$\rightarrow \frac{[a + b]^{3/2} + [a - b]^{3/2}}{[c + d]^{3/2} - [c - d]^{3/2}}$$
Now I can put the formulas $(a^3 + b^3)$ and $(c^3 - d^3)$
$$\rightarrow \frac{[(a + b)^{1/2} + (a - b)^{1/2}][(a + b) - \sqrt{a^2 - b^2} + (a - b)]}{[(c + d)^{1/2} - (c - d)^{1/2}][(c + d) + \sqrt{c^2 - d^2} + (c - d]}$$
$$\rightarrow \frac{7[(a + b)^{1/2} + (a - b)^{1/2}]}{13[(c + d)^{1/2} - (c - d)^{1/2}]}$$
From here, I do not know how to proceed. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Rationalizing the denominator might be a useful first step.

Comment: Why not get rid of the cubes by cubing each term. They're not that big. Then you'll only need to worry about square roots.

Comment: @rogerl tried rationalizing but of no use.

Comment: Can you guess $\sqrt{8+2\sqrt{15}}$

Comment: If $\sqrt{8 + 2\sqrt{15}} = x$ Then I have $60 = (x^2 - 8)^2$. Not sure about a better way, and how would guessing that help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply square the expression. A lot of cancelation will happen and you'll end up in $490/1690$.  Now take square root to get the final answer $7/13$.

Comment: You were right, and honestly I find this answer to be the simplest.

Answer (score 4):

$$\sqrt{8+2\sqrt{15}}=\sqrt5+\sqrt3$$

Comment: How will this help?

Comment: How is that related to $\sqrt{4+\sqrt{15}}$

Comment: Got it, so we need to multiple both sides by $2$?

Comment: @Anonymous By $\sqrt{2}$.

Answer (score 0):

$$\frac{[4 + \sqrt{15}]^{3/2} + [4 - \sqrt{15}]^{3/2}}{[6 + \sqrt{35}]^{3/2} - [6 - \sqrt{35}]^{3/2}}$$
$$=\frac{[4 + \sqrt{15}]^{3/2} + [4 - \sqrt{15}]^{3/2}}{[6 + \sqrt{35}]^{3/2} - [6 - \sqrt{35}]^{3/2}}\times\frac{2^{3/2}}{2^{3/2}}$$
$$=\frac{[8+2\sqrt{15}]^{3/2} + [8-2\sqrt{15}]^{3/2}}{[12+2\sqrt{35}]^{3/2} - [12-2\sqrt{35}]^{3/2}}$$
$$=\frac{[\sqrt5+\sqrt3]^3 + [\sqrt5-\sqrt3]^3}{[\sqrt7+\sqrt5]^3 - [\sqrt7-\sqrt5]^3}$$
$$=\frac{28\sqrt{5}}{52\sqrt{5}}$$
$$=\frac{7}{13}$$